# How to pass a "phrase" parameter to a Wordpress shortcode and get the whole "phrase"

Tags: string, parameters, shortcode

I hope your are fine,

**I am making a Wordpress shortcode that has a parameter**. I can pass that parameter **throught that shortcode**, but I notice that **only the first word** of the string passes, and nothing else.

How can I make sure I get the whole string.

Here is what I did in order to pass the parameter to the shortcode :

- This is how I pass the parameter :

```
do_shortcode( ' [list_documents titre='.$titre.']' );
```

where $titre is the variable that contains the parameter.

- This is how I get the parameter in shortcode function :

```
function list_documents_func( $attr ){        
$option = shortcode_atts( array( 'titre' => ''), $attr );
echo "The title I get is : " . $option['titre'];
}
```

Please can somebody help me understand how to make sure the string that I get the whole string that passes through the do_shortcode ?